# Simple if statement problem

Tags: java, if-statement, tostring

I am trying to return a toString if something is true.

I have this code:

```
    public void printoutsailings() {
    for (Sailing s:sailings) {
        String hamburg = ("Hamburg");
        if ((s.getDeparturePort()) == hamburg) {
            System.out.println(s.toStringAdjusted());
        }

  }
}
```

However I get nothing when I run the method (when I should be getting something). I assume that I have somehow messed up the logic or not understood =,== and eq properly, I'm not too sure.

There is nothing wrong with the toString or the for loop, and I'm not getting any compiler or run time errors. It's just that the logic is wrong.

If someone could put me right that'd be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What happened to the source code sample that was here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using `.equals()` instead of `==` to check `String` equality.  Try the following:

```
if ((s.getDeparturePort()).equals(hamburg)) {
    System.out.println(s.toStringAdjusted());
}
```

In short, `==` checks to see if two strings are the exact same reference, and `.equals()` checks to see if two strings look the same.

It should also be said that you need to use `.equals()` for checking the equality of any `Object` type, not just strings.  Only primitive types (`int`, `double`, `char`) should use `==` for equality.

To compensate for the fact that the departure might be null, simply switch the condition around.  It would read - `hamburg.equals(s.getDeparturePort())`

Comment: @jjnguy, if `s.getDeparturePort()` is null, then your solution will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: Which may be entirely the right thing to do, of course :)

Comment: thanks for the explanation, i can't believe I managed to do this as I was already using equals() elsewhere in my code doh!

i plan to avoid the nullpointerexception by having an else if which will cover all other bases. thank you :)

Comment: @jjnguy and @JonSkeet, or he could avoid that and use 'hamburg'.equals(s.getDeparturePort())

Comment: @josh, agreed.  I actually have that info at the end of my post.

Comment: @jjnguy, oh wow I really blanked out on that one... sorry, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 6):

Yup, you're relying on == comparing for equality rather than identity. Change the code to:

```
if (s.getDeparturePort().equals("hamburg")) {
    System.out.println(s.toStringAdjusted());
}
```

For reference types, == in Java *always* means "compare the two *references* for equality". In other words, it returns whether two references refer to the same object.

You want to check whether the two strings are *equal* instead - i.e. whether they contain the same sequence of characters. That's what the overridden `equals` method is for.

(To give a real-world demonstration of this, I catch a number 36 bus every morning. To me those buses are *equal* because they take me on the same route, but I know there are several number 36 buses - I don't get on the exact same physical bus every day.)

Note that the code above will throw a `NullPointerException` if `s.getDeparturePort()` returns `null`. There are two ways of avoiding this. First, you can use a known-to-be-non-null reference as the target of the method call:

```
if ("hamburg".equals(s.getDeparturePort()))
```

Alternatively, you can perform an explicit nullity check:

```
String port = s.getDeparturePort();
if (port != null && port.equals("hamburg"))
```

Or you can leave it to throw an exception, if that's the most appropriate behaviour (i.e. if you really don't expect `getDeparturePort()` to return null, and want to blow up if you get such bad data rather than continuing and possibly propagating the problem).

Comment: What if `getDeparturePort()` returns `null`?

Comment: thanks for the explanation, i can't believe I managed to do this as I was already using equals() elsewhere in my code doh!

i plan to avoid the nullpointerexception by having an else if which will cover all other bases. thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You must compare strings using `equals` method.

In Java, `String` is a **reference type**. It means that your `String hamburg`, pointing to a variable in the stack, contains a **reference** to a managed heap object actually containing the string. A value type, conversely, is completely allocated into the stack.

The `==`, read *reference equals* compares the stack values. Instead, all classes implement an `equals` method that is read *value compare*. It compares the real values of the object wherever they are allocated in.

The following code works for you:

```
public void printoutsailings() { 
    for (Sailing s:sailings) { 
        String hamburg = ("Hamburg"); 
        if (hamburg.equals(s.getDeparturePort())) { //First hamburg to prevent any possible NullPointerException
            System.out.println(s.toStringAdjusted()); 
        } 

  } 
}
```

Just for your curiosity:

1. PHP only compares by value
2. C# redefines the `==` operator as a *value equals* operator, but **only** for the `string` class
3. In VB.NET, the default `=` operator is the *value equals* operator. The `Is` operator corresponds to the *reference equals*

Comment: Java doesn't have a `Equals` method (I see you included it in your code too. Instead, it has an `equals()` method.

Comment: Haha, looks like I mispelled the case. Thanks

Comment: and you haven't updated your mistakes yet...no fret, I've done it.

Comment: @elite: hahahahaha, in fact I fixed my comment because I was too lazy to fix :-P (an answer has been already accepted). Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

In String, equality is checked either by `equals()` method or `compareTo()` method.

Your solution can be fixed by:

```
if (s.getDeparturePort().equals(hamburg)) {
    System.out.println(s.toStringAdjusted());
}
```

To avoid receiving a `null` from `s.getDeparturePort()`, I would do the following.

```
if ("Hamburg".equals(s.getDeparturePort())) {
    System.out.println(s.toStringAdjusted());
}
```

This is to avoid `NullPointerException` if `s.getDeparturePort()` is `null` (from your example code).

Alternatively, you can use the `compareTo()` method like so....

Your changed code (to using `compareTo()`:

```
if (s.getDeparturePort().compareTo(hamburg) == 0) {
    System.out.println(s.toStringAdjusted());
}
```

My alternate solution (using `compareTo()`)

```
if ("Hamburg".compareTo(s.getDeparturePort()) == 0) { //Zero means that it is equal.
    System.out.println(s.toStringAdjusted());
}
```

Btw...

```
String hamburg = ("Hamburg");
```

can be easily written as

```
String hamburg = "Hamburg";
```

Comment: @Ben Smith, glad to have been of help. :)

Comment: +1 for recommending to drop the brackets in the String declaration/assigment.

Answer (score 2):

`if(hamburg.equals(s.getDeparturePort()))`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public void printoutsailings() {
    for (Sailing s:sailings) {
        String hamburg = "Hamburg";
        if (s.getDeparturePort().equals(hamburg)) {
            System.out.println(s.toStringAdjusted());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`==` is comparing the object itself, you're better off using `.equals()` as it will compare the actual value of the String, such as :

```
if ((s.equals(hamburg)) {
            System.out.println(s.toStringAdjusted());
        }
```

Also make sure that `Sailings` has at least 1 value, otherwise you'll never enter that for loop anyway

Answer (score 0):

Instead of simply providing the code...check [this](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html) out, I am almost certain it will get you to where you need to go...

Answer (score 0):

try `if (s.getDeparturePort().equals(hamburg))`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using == for String objects (or any objects), use .compareTo(), as in this example:

http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/12stringcomparison.html